# jmeter - How add 2 different product from csv

Tags: csv, jmeter

I have problem with my test. I'm doing test for online shop. I want add few different products to basket   In csv file I have products

product 1

product 2

product 3

..........  100

I'm adding  product 1 and then I want add product 2 from next line csv file but Jmeter take as next product 1 one more time .

How add next product from csv file ?

That's my setup

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pS21B.png)

Comment: you can take any number of products. it is based on how you configured. please let us know the threads, loop count, CSV configuration values, so that we can suggest precise answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSV data should be comma delimited. [image]

This data you can load into the CSV data set config comma seperated
[image]

And you can post same data in your respective HTTP request
[image]

Hope this helps you :)

[image]

Comment: Hi Mark, did u try my answer?

Comment: Hi, Yes  I've tried. My setup looks the same. I've added some screenshot  in my post . Please look.

Comment: Try adding data horizontally like all product_id in first row, all product in second row and all SA in third row

Comment: I can't, because one product has 3 id (config product_id, simple product_id , size_id) I have to add all of them in one row.